# How to speed up selenium tests on AWS device farm?

Tags: selenium, aws-device-farm

I'm using Python for testing on AWS device farm. It seems that starting a selenium takes very very long. This is the code I use:

```py
from time import time

from boto3 import client
from selenium import webdriver


def main():
    start = time()

    device_farm_client = client("devicefarm", region_name='us-west-2')

    test_grid_url_response = device_farm_client.create_test_grid_url(
        expiresInSeconds=666,
        projectArn="arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:..."
    )

    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=test_grid_url_response['url'],
        desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
    )

    driver.get('https://api.ipify.org')
    print(f"Your IP is: {driver.find_element_by_tag_name('pre').text}")

    driver.quit()

    print(f"took: {time() - start:.2f}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Your IP is: 100.10.10.111
took: 99.89s
```

Using existing selenium-hub infrastructure the IP is obtained in less than 2 seconds!

Is there any way how to reduce the time radically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the overall execution time for complete test suite execution take advantage of the 50 concurrent sessions given you by default at no cost. Check this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/testgrid/techref-limits.html). For eg:

Lets assume following details

- one test Suite has 200 Selenium test cases
- each test case takes around 10 seconds to execute
- One AWS Device Farm Selenium Session takes around 60 seconds to start

then I will divide my 200 test cases into 50 concurrent sessions by running concurrent batches of 4 test cases per session.

**Total Execution Time = (60 seconds to start each session + 10 seconds to start all 50 concurrent sessions with rate of 5 sessions per second + 4*10 seconds to execute the test cases in each session) = 60+10+40 = 110 seconds to finish complete test suite execution**

WHEREAS

If you are existing selenium-hub infrastructure and lets say following details are assumed

- 200 Selenium test cases to execute
- 2 seconds to start a session
- assume at max you can run 10 concurrent sessions

**Total Execution Time = 2 seconds to start each session + 20*10 seconds to execute the test cases in each session = 200+2 = 202 seconds to finish complete test suite execution**

Comment: thank you for your answer! Though, the use case cannot be parallelized and therefor I cannot accept you answer. Sorry :(

Comment: I believe geek2geek_AWS answer is acceptable.
If your Selenium tests are not designed for parallel, there is no point to use the Selenium grid and Device Farm.